# Indexing an array in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an array in visual basic.net that is currently over 400 million values. I was wondering - how do I easily create an index of this array and store it to a save file to reduce the time spent iterating through the array and locating the 1st 0 for example. Also - if I am iterating 400 million times to locate the value I seek, don't I have to iterate through the index as instead? If this is the case, how does the index (which will be a larger array likely) improve my variable retrieval time if I simply end up having to iterate through a larger array?! (Maybe I've not thought this part through properly)

Indexes are very useful for speedup in MySQL Db's so this should be implementable.

Thanks in advance
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a whole class of software called data bases that are specifically designed to store and retrieve data in an efficient manner.  Any index you write will be some implementation of a well know algorithm already written and tuned in a DBMS.  For .net you first choose would be sql server.

Comment: Yeah I may utilise sql server to do this.. I just need to learn how to use it (thanks ms for msdn), hopefully I should be able to get large indexes :)